# Access names of checked nodes without all the sub nodes' names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using **jstree** and I want to access the IDs and names of all checked nodes in my **HTML** tree in order to present them together in a summary.

This is my code:

```
$("#summary").click(function () {

    var id_arr = new Array();
    var text_arr = new Array();

    $("#tree").jstree('get_checked').each(function (index) {
        id_arr.push($(this).attr("id"));
        text_arr.push($(this).text());
    });

    alert("Your Selection: " + id_arr.join() + " " + text_arr.join());

});
```

While `id_arr.push($(this).attr("id"));` returns only the IDs of the relevant checked nodes (*only* the parent node ID when all children of the parent node are checked as well), `text_arr.push($(this).text());` returns *all* the names of the checked nodes (name of checked parent *and* names of all of its children).

Do you have any ideas how to return only the names of the checked parent?
I already considered adding a hidden HTML attribute (as in `<li id="123"> <a title="ID:123" hidden="name of node 123">name of node 123</a></li>`) to my tree nodes and using **.attr("hidden")** instead of accessing **node.text()** but I think that there must be a better solution.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update:**

The HTML of the tree (my real tree is quite extensive but I think this one will do):

```
<div id="tree">
    <li id="123"> <a title="ID:123">tree</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="234"> <a title="ID:234">leaf tree</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="345"> <a title="ID:345">oak</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="456"> <a title="ID:456">white oak</a></li>
                            <li id="567"> <a title="ID:567">German oak</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="678"> <a title="ID:678">lime</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="789"> <a title="ID:789">conifer</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="890"> <a title="ID:890">pine</a></li>
                    <li id="901"> <a title="ID:901">spruce</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>       
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

Example: When choosing "oak", the return should be only "345 oak" and not "345 oak white oak German oak".

By the way, my idea with "hidden" doesn't work, because the elements written in there are, well, *hidden*.

Comment: please add the html of the tree to your question.after that it will be easier to write the correct script

Comment: @spring: I added the HTML of an example tree with the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
text_arr.push($(this).find("a:first").text());
```

The result of **.text()** is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements; in this case all text contained between the **li**-tags of the element referenced by **$(this)**, including the text of the sub nodes.

By adding `.find("a:first").text()` only the text between the first **a**-tag is contained in the string.